# How to make Discord.py bot send message to server owner?

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-3.8

I would like the bot to send a message to the server owner in private message. (using Python3.8 and discord.py).
I already tried this :

```
await ctx.guild.owner.send("Thanks for inviting the bot! type .help to see all the commands")
```

But I got the error :

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

If it helps, both Privileged Gateway Intents (*presence intent* and *server members intent*) are enabled.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable `intents.members`

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

Also make sure to enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)